# Response Redirection Failed to work

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, redirect, post

I want to pass FB response from client end to server end ( code behind )

```
 function testAPI() {
            console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
            FB.api('/me', function (response) {

                $.post('http://localhost:4741/Default.aspx',
                { fbid: response.id, firstname: response.first_name, lastname: response.last_name, email: response.email, bday: response.birthday }, 
                function (result) {

                });
                 console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.id + response.name + response.id + response.email + response.gender + response.birthday + '.');

            });
        }
```

I'd like to get the value and process in page load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var fbid = Request.Form["fbid"];
            var fname = Request.Form["firstname"];
            var lname = Request.Form["lastname"];
            var email = Request.Form["email"];
            var bday = Request.Form["bday"];
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                if (fbid != null)
                {

                    if (CheckFBLogin(fbid.ToString()) == true)
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("Users.aspx");
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("Register.aspx");
                    }
                }
            }



        }
```

the CheckFBLogin(fbid.ToString()) is function located in same code behind page. but when pass the Response.Redirect("Register.aspx",true); there's nothing happen. it'll stay in the same page.

what supposesd to fix ?

Comment: So if CheckFBLogin succeeds you redirect to Register.aspx, and if it fails - you do the same thing ? Is there a typo here ?

Comment: okay I think there's typo but, both of the response.redirect didn't works

Answer (score 1):

You're passing 'true' in the 'endResponse' parameter to Response.Redirect. This will cause the current request to end, causing a ThreadAbortException. If you're not handling this, or you're handling it by simply swallowing the exception, your redirect will appear to 'not work'. Passing 'false' is recommended.

Comment: hello there I tried to remove and also change into false. yes the page still not redirected. is it myjquery code err ?

Comment: I don't think so, as that's not where you're redirecting, you're just doing an http post. Can you set a breakpoint on your pageLoad and step through it ? Is it even hitting the Response.Redirects ? Can you check the eventlog for any exception you're not handling ?

Comment: yes it pass throught the response redirect line. but it'll recall the site master and not moving to page

Comment: ok, in your browser can you open the debugger, go to the network tab and see what response code you're getting ?

Comment: yes I debug them and hit breakpoint on register page. but still in the deafult.apx